# How to put 3 columns in 1 ODOO

Tags: python, xml, odoo, erp, odoo-14

I need to store the values of three columns in one column
But the tree view does not allow me to transform or change it in any way
What can I do in this case?
My module: academy

```
<record id="view_academy_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">academy.tree</field>
        <field name="model">academy</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="lastname"/>
                <field name="age"/>
                <field name="description"/>
                <field name="date"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>



from odoo import models, fields, api

class academy(models.Model):
    _name = 'academy'
    _description = 'academy'

name = fields.Char(string="Имя")
lastname = fields.Char(string="Фамилия")
age = fields.Integer(string="Возраст")
description = fields.Text(string="Дополнительно")
image = fields.Binary(string="Фотография")

def _default_my_date(self):
    return fields.Date.context_today(self)

date = fields.Date(string="Дата", default=_default_my_date)
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean.  Do you mean you want to merge three fields into one column?  If so, you can create a computed field to combine them and then add that field to your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you want to do 2 things, first is combine 3 fields into one, which can be done with a computed field.

The second is changing the tree view to show the new field instead of the other 3 which you can do by replacing the view:
Example:

```
 <record  model="ir.ui.view" id="custom_academy_tree">
    <field name="name">academy.tree.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">academy.tree</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="*the_form_id*"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="academy_tree" position="replace">
            <tree>
            <field name="old_field1"/>
            <field name="old_field2"/>
            <field name="new_field"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: ref="*the_form_id*" - what is this?

Comment: @Dread the id of the view that contains the tree field.